How do I make my navbar items vertical while letting the logo and icon stay on top
It's my first time doing some responsive design and I use this as an excercise. But after trying this for several hours I'm desperate now. So I have a simple Navbar with a logo at the left corner, four nav-items in the middle and three buttons at the right.
When the viewport is reaching a width of 912px, I hide the nav-items in the middle. Now only the Logo at the left stays and the three buttons at the right are replaced with a burger menu icon.
When I click on the hamburger menu icon, the nav-items should appear and stack vertically below the logo and menu icon. But they are just appearing somewhere between the the logo and the menu. At this point I'm too unexperienced to resolve the issue. So I'm kindly asking for help.
Link to JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0nrc1wq4/1/
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&display=swap"
          rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="navbar.css" />
    </head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <img src="../images/logo-small.svg" alt="Logo" id="icon-logo" class="corner-item-left" />
            <ul>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#Willkommen">Willkommen</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#Wohnen">Wohnen</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#Kleinwalsertal">Kleinwalsertal</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#Kontakt">Kontakt</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul>
                <li class="icon-item"><button class="icon-button" id="icon-phone"><img src="../images/icon-phone.svg" alt="Telefon"/></button></li>
                <li class="icon-item"><button class="icon-button" id="icon-contact"><img src="../images/icon-contact.svg" alt="Kontakt"/></button></li>
                <li class="icon-item"><button class="icon-button corner-item-right" id="icon-booking"><img src="../images/icon-booking.svg" alt="Buchen"/></button></li>
            </ul>
            <button class="burger-menu-button" id="burger-menu">☰</button>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <script>
        const burgerMenu = document.getElementById("burger-menu");
        const logo = document.getElementById("icon-logo");
        const navUl = document.querySelector("nav ul");

        function toggleMenu() {
            toggleLogo();
            toggleBurgerMenuIcon();
            toggleNavVisibility();
        }

        function toggleLogo() {
                if (logo.src.includes("logo-small.svg")) {
                    logo.src = "../images/logo-filled.svg";
                } else {
                    logo.src = "../images/logo-small.svg";
                }
        }

        function toggleBurgerMenuIcon() {
            if (burgerMenu.innerHTML === "☰") {
                burgerMenu.innerHTML = "✖";
            } else {
                burgerMenu.innerHTML = "☰";
            }
        }

        function toggleNavVisibility() {
            navUl.classList.toggle("nav-visible");
        }

        burgerMenu.addEventListener("click", toggleMenu);
    </script>
</body>

HTML & JS:
Thank you in advance!

@DA OP said it in first line: first time doing responsive design and excercise. I think that's a solid reason.

@DA I usually use bootstrap. It's a homework from the vocational school I visit, because of my apprenticeship. Sadly the schools here are far behind the modern frameworks. To give you an example: I work as a dev for 3 years now. The third year is the last year before exam. In school they just started to teach us about "Overloading and Overriding"... But I also just like to know the backgrounds before bootstrap existed

Is not the cleanest approach but it can give you a direction on how to do it.
I used here also some variables just to remember you about them and you should use them more in your study/example.


            const burgerMenu = document.getElementById("burger-menu");
            const logo = document.getElementById("icon-logo");
            const navUl = document.querySelector("nav ul");

            function toggleMenu() {
                toggleLogo();
                toggleBurgerMenuIcon();
                toggleNavVisibility();
            }

            function toggleLogo() {
                    if (logo.src.includes("logo-small.svg")) {
                        logo.src = "../images/logo-filled.svg";
                    } else {
                        logo.src = "../images/logo-small.svg";
                    }
            }

            function toggleBurgerMenuIcon() {
                if (burgerMenu.innerHTML === "☰") {
                    burgerMenu.innerHTML = "✖";
                } else {
                    burgerMenu.innerHTML = "☰";
                }
            }

            function toggleNavVisibility() {
                navUl.classList.toggle("nav-visible");
            }

            burgerMenu.addEventListener("click", toggleMenu);
:root {
  --menu-height: 80px;  
  --left-space:20px;
}

body {
    background: #7A593E;
    margin:0px;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.corner-item-left {
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.corner-item-right {
    margin-right: 20px;
}

 .menuLayer
 {
   width:100%;
   display:flex;
   align-items: center;    
 }

/* Navbar */
nav {
    background: #FFFFFF 0 0 no-repeat padding-box;
    display: flex;    
    width: 100%;
    height: var(--menu-height);
}

nav ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

nav ul li {
    margin-left: 20px;
}

nav img {
    height: 60px;
}

/* Mitte */
.nav-item {
    margin-left: 50px;
    font: normal normal normal 20px/80px Montserrat;
}

.nav-item a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #AF8C6E;
}

.nav-link {
    position: relative;
}

.nav-link::after {
    content: '';
    height: 4px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #C59E7C;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -4px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.2s;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.nav-link:hover::after {
    opacity: 1;
}

/* Buttons rechts */
.icon-item {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.icon-button {
    background-color: #C59E7C;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 30px;
    padding: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.icon-button img {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
}

.burger-menu-button {
    color: #C59E7C;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}

#icon-booking {
    background-color: #BEA56C !important;
}

.nav-visible {
    display: flex !important;
}

/* Responsive */

@media screen and (max-width: 912px) {
    
    nav
    {
      justify-content:space-between;
    }
    
    .menuLayer
    {      
      position:absolute;
      top:var(--menu-height);
      left:0;
      z-index:10;
      background-color:green;
      overflow-y:auto;
      overflow-x:hidden;
      justify-content:space-between;      
      max-width:300px;       
      min-width:200px;
    }
    
    .nav-item {
      margin:0px;        
      padding-left:var(--left-space);      
    }
    
    nav ul {
        display: none;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
    }

    nav ul li {
        margin: 0;
        width:100%;        
    }

    .burger-menu-button {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    
}
<?php
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Aufgabe 3</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100..900;1,100..900&display=swap"
              rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="navbar.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <nav>
                <img src="../images/logo-small.svg" alt="Logo" id="icon-logo" class="corner-item-left" />
                <div class="menuLayer">
                                
                  <ul>
                      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#Willkommen">Willkommen</a></li>
                      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#Wohnen">Wohnen</a></li>
                      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#Kleinwalsertal">Kleinwalsertal</a></li>
                      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#Kontakt">Kontakt</a></li>
                  </ul>
                  <ul>
                      <li class="icon-item"><button class="icon-button" id="icon-phone"><img src="../images/icon-phone.svg" alt="Telefon"/></button></li>
                      <li class="icon-item"><button class="icon-button" id="icon-contact"><img src="../images/icon-contact.svg" alt="Kontakt"/></button></li>
                      <li class="icon-item"><button class="icon-button corner-item-right" id="icon-booking"><img src="../images/icon-booking.svg" alt="Buchen"/></button></li>
                  </ul>                
                
                </div>
                <button class="burger-menu-button" id="burger-menu">☰</button>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </body>
</html>




Okay it almost works. But I just realized in desktop view the menu layer kinda destroys the alignment of the items in the navbar. :')
